Declare italics for certain rows and columns
A continuation to a previous question I had with an unclaimed account.
How to italicize the letters (k, kh, etc. all the way to o) without wrapping each letter with \textit{}? Is there a way to declare italics for designated rows/columns?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{{\small Compound}}
\newcommand{\NA}{---}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={l *{11}{c}},
        hlines, vlines,
        row{1-5}={font=\small},
      }
      \SetCell[r=5]{c,h} {Place of \\ Articulation} & \SetCell[c=11]{c} Manner of Articulation \\
      & \SetCell[c=7]{c} Consonants &&&&&&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} Vowels &&& \SetCell[r=4]{c,h} {Pure \\ Nasal} \\
      & \SetCell[c=5]{c} Stops &&&&
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c,h} {Semi \\ vowel \\ (voiced)}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c,h} {Sibilant \\ (voiceless)}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c} \rotcell{Short}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c} \rotcell{Long}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c} \rotcell{Compound} & \\
      & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Voiceless && \SetCell[c=3]{c} Voiced \\
      & {non- \\ aspirate} & aspirate & {non- \\ aspirate} & aspirate & nasal \\
      Gutturals  & k & kh & g & gh & ṅ & h  &   & a & ā & e & \\
      Palatals   & c & ch & j & jh & ñ & y  &   & i & ī & \SetCell[r=3]{}  & \\
      Cerebrals  & ṭ & ṭh & ḍ & ḍh & ṇ & r\,/\,l\,/\,ḷh & & \SetCell[r=2]{} & \SetCell[r=2]{} & & ṁ \\
      Dentals    & t & th & d & dh & n & l  & s &   &   &   &     \\
      Labials    & p & ph & b & bh & m & v  &   & u & ū & o &     \\
    \end{tblr}}
\end{table}

\end{document}


Off-topic, but please don't scale elements which contain text. Either choose a suitable font size instead or change the layout of your table

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Okay I edited the code above. What part of the code is scaling elements and what issues does scaling potentially cause?

You can ask stackexchange to merge your accounts

Never do \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% to tables: it removes any chance of consistent font sizes.

@paladhammika The \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...} is scaling elements which contain text. It will lead to inconsistent font sizes in your document and make your document  look like a ransom letter

I see. How would I then properly resize the table to fit the text width and into the margin? After commenting out the resize box the table runs over the margins.
The table has been in the document for well over a year and I haven't seen any ransom letter haha.

see the posted answer (which uses \small then adjusts the column spacing to fit) . You would not justify text in a paragraph by scaling the text to arbitrarily large or small  size to make things fit, but for some reason some sites recommend doing that to text in a table.

This can be achieved with the option cell{6-Z}{2-11}={font=\itshape}. Here Z denotes the last row.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\rotcell}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}
%\begin{table}[ht]
%  \centering
%  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec={l *{11}{c}},
        hlines, vlines,
        row{1-5}={font=\small},
        cell{6-Z}{2-11}={font=\itshape}
      }
      \SetCell[r=5]{c,h} {Place of \\ Articulation} & \SetCell[c=11]{c} Manner of Articulation \\
      & \SetCell[c=7]{c} Consonants &&&&&&& \SetCell[c=3]{c} Vowels &&& \SetCell[r=4]{c,h} {Pure \\ Nasal} \\
      & \SetCell[c=5]{c} Stops &&&&
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c,h} {Semi \\ vowel \\ (voiced)}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c,h} {Sibilant \\ (voiceless)}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c} \rotcell{Short}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c} \rotcell{Long}
      & \SetCell[r=3]{c} \rotcell{Compound} & \\
      & \SetCell[c=2]{c} Voiceless && \SetCell[c=3]{c} Voiced \\
      & {non- \\ aspirate} & aspirate & {non- \\ aspirate} & aspirate & nasal \\
      Gutturals  & k & kh & g & gh & ṅ & h  &   & a & ā & e & \\
      Palatals   & c & ch & j & jh & ñ & y  &   & i & ī & \SetCell[r=3]{}  & \\
      Cerebrals  & ṭ & ṭh & ḍ & ḍh & ṇ & r\,/\,l\,/\,ḷh & & \SetCell[r=2]{} & \SetCell[r=2]{} & & ṁ \\
      Dentals    & t & th & d & dh & n & l  & s &   &   &   &     \\
      Labials    & p & ph & b & bh & m & v  &   & u & ū & o &     \\
    \end{tblr}%}
%\end{table}
\end{document}


